# trigger CSS animation with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, css-animations

I update the content of a div with a JavaScript function and i want to trigger animation on the div each time a new mailbox is loaded.

But the animation get triggered once on reload or when i'm switched back from another div .
Notice that i'm *switching* beetween `divs`by tweaking the `display`attribute of each `div`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));

  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
}



function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#mail-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)} </h3>`;

}
```

I wrote the animation and link the div to it expecting the animation will load on each function call but instead of that the animation loads on reach refresh of the page.

```
#emails-view {
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


@keyframes grow {
    0% { top: 0%;
        }
    30% {top: 50%;
    }
    100% {top: 0%;
    }
}

#emails-view {
    animation-name: grow;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The HTML is that :

```
<hr>

<div id="emails-view">
</div>

<div id="mail-view" class="card">
    <div id="mail-header" class="card-header">
        <div style="font-weight:bold;" id='mail-sender'></div>
        <div style="font-weight:bold;" id='mail-receiver'></div>
    </div>
    <div id="card-body-1" class="card-body">
      <h5 style="font-weight:bold;" id="mail-subject" class="card-title"></h5>
      <p id="mail-time" class="card-text"></p>
      <a id="mail-button-reply" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">reply</a>
      <a id="mail-button-archive" href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Archive</a>
    </div>
    <div id="card-body-2" class="card-body">
        <p style="font-size: 20px;" id="mail-content" class="card-text"></p>
    </div>

  </div>

<div id="compose-view">
    <h3>New Email</h3>
    <form id="compose-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input style="font: bold; font-size: 30px;" class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
        <textarea style="font-size: 20px;" class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
        <input style="color: white;" id='compose-submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Mail"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it retrigger if you remove and re-add the id? If so you could move the animation to a new class and set up some JS which does this for you when you need to the have the animation happen. Something like: `document.getElementById("myelement").classList.remove("mystyle");` and `document.getElementById("myelement").classList.add("mystyle");`

Comment: I just try it but the animation keep starting on reload. I think the problem is that the animation iteration is by default 1 and i'm displaying the same page with different content . So the animation runs only one time (on page loaded) in my case.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Also, I'm not seeing anything that would re-trigger the animation each click. The `load_mailbox` function sets the display of `#email-view` to `block`, but nothing's setting it to `none` or anything else. So why do you expect the animation to re-trigger?

Comment: I expect the animation to re-trigger every time  i update the content of the `#email-view` by passing a different `mailbox` to the `load_mailbox`

Comment: the html looks like : `<div id="emails-view"> </div>`

Comment: i updated the question with the `#emails-view` CSS and all the `HTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a fix animating the div directly from JavaScript `animate` method.

I wrote a function to find and apply the animation

```
function animate(view){
  element = document.querySelector('${view}').animate([
    // keyframes
    {opacity: '0'},
    {opacity : '1'}
  ],
  // timing options
  {
    duration:1000,

  })}
```

and i'm trigerring the function each time i load a `mailbox`

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#mail-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // animate current view
  animate('#emails-view')
}
```

Comment: That's also a good solution, especially for simple animations. I actually wasn't aware of the `element.animate()` function, I thought that was jQuery for a second. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

The way I trigger CSS animations with JavaScript is to attach the animation to a class:

```css
.animate {
    animation-name: grow;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Then add the class to the selected element with JS while removing from others

```js
document.querySelector('#emails-view').classList.add('animate');
```

Then you may want to remove the class when the animation is over

```js
// notice we use `function` and not `() => {}`, it's more convenient
// in this case because it gives access to `this.classList`
document.querySelector('#emails-view').onanimationend = function() {
  this.classList.remove('animate');
}
```